# When was the expression "фунт презрения" introduced?

Tags: выражения, идиомы, история-языка

I am wondering when the expression фунт презрения was introduced. On Google Books, the **oldest** occurrence of фунт презрения seems to be in Slezkin's [Козел в огороде](https://books.google.com/books?id=ANIeAAAAIAAJ) (1923):

> Но только в силу моего мягкого характера Марьянка на все это ноль
> внимания, фунт презрения. — Говорят вам, нет ничего! И понимаете,
> даже с такой обидой в голосе, точно бы я тиран или деспот домашний

This is corroborated by the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=25&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0).

I assume that the books digitized by Google come mostly from American libraries. However, since I am not familiar with the [Digital Leninka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_State_Library), this is the best I can do at the moment.

I am looking for **older** occurrences of фунт презрения. The older, the better.

Comment: . И. Куприн. На переломе (Кадеты) (1900)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)
― Прохожу мимо ― нуль внимания и фунт презрения. [А. И. Куприн. На переломе (Кадеты) (1900)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole idiom consists of two parts, i.e. Ноль внимания, фунт презрения.

Ruscorpora.ru gives the earliest mentioning of the fist part by Чехов.

А какое, мой друг, несчастие, какая насмешка быть сутулым, лохматым, сереньким, порядочным и неглупым, и влюбиться в эту хорошенькую и глупенькую девочку, которая на вас **ноль внимания**! [А. П. Чехов. Красавицы (1888)

And the whole phrase a bit later by Куприн.

. И. Куприн. На переломе (Кадеты) (1900) [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)
― Прохожу мимо ― **нуль внимания и фунт презрения**. [А. И. Куприн. На переломе (Кадеты) (1900)